# Unable to build docker container

Tags: docker, apt-get

I'm trying to run my Dockerfile script and I'm facing this error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, may be run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

This happens at line
`RUN apt-get install curl`

I tried doing : `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl` but I had then faced this:
"After this operation, 339 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command `/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install curl` returned a non-zero code: 1
"
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `apt-get -y install curl`.  The `-y` causes apt to proceed without prompting for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y curl
```